# How to use Pass by Value in Java

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

```
public class Test {

        public void Receiving (int var)
        {
          var = var + 2;
        }

        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
          int passing = 3;

          Receiving (passing);

          System.out.println("The value of passing is: " +passing);
        }    
    }
```

When i compiled this code... i got this error.

```
Test.java:12: non-static method Receiving(int) cannot be referenced from a static context
  Receiving (passing);
  ^
```

Now When i changed my method Receiving into `static`, the output was....

```
The value of passing is: 3
```

Now how can i pass the value 3 into the method Receiving so that the output is 5 printed in the console.

Comment: Is this an extension of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277740/pass-by-value-in-java

Comment: I think you mean *how to use pass by reference*, not *how to pass by value*, since it really **is passed by value here**.

Comment: FYI, The `static`-ness of the method has nothing to do with how parameters are passed.

Answer (score 6):

This is generally not possible in Java, because primitive types are always passed by value, not by reference. Even if you used the `Integer` wrapper class instead of `int`, you couldn't change that because `Integer` is immutable.

You can, however use this trick:

```
public class Test {

    // static is necessary, as you already found out
    public static void Receiving (int[] var)
    {
      var[0] = var[0] + 2;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
      int[] passing = new int[] {3};
      Receiving (passing);
      System.out.println("The value of passing is: " +passing[0]);
    }    
}
```

Comment: all types are passed by value

Comment: all types are either primitive types or reference types. primitives are passed by values. references are passed by value. see other answers

Comment: @newacct: OK, yes. I know that. You can correct my answer if you feel this information is missing from it. I thought this was about primitive type (OP's question), so I wasn't going into the depths of the JLS

Answer (score 5):

That wouldn't be *pass-by-value*, that would be *pass-by-reference*!  Pass-by-value effectively means that the method works on a copy of the original variable.  (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy).  Java is always pass-by-value.

For primitive types (e.g. `int`, `float`, etc.), if you want to have the input value modified by the method, you can simply return it:

```
public static int Receiving(int var) {
    return var + 2;
}

...

passing = Receiving(passing);
```

Answer (score 3):

Java is pass by value, but you have to be clear about what's passed: it's the reference to an object or value, not the object or value itself.  You can't modify that reference, but you may be able to change the state of the object it points to (as long as it's mutable).

so you'll never see the output "5" in your console.  That's not how Java works.  The JVM has already made the clear.

Answer (score 3):

> Now how can i pass the value 3 into
>   the method Receiving so that the
>   output is 5 printed in the console.

You could wrap the integer so that it will be passed as a refernce:

```
public class Test {

    class Wrapper {
        int var;

        Wrapper(int val) {
            var = val;
        }
    }

    public void Receiving(Wrapper w) {
        w.var = w.var + 2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        Wrapper passing = test.new Wrapper(3);
        test.Receiving(passing);
        System.out.println("The value of passing is: " + passing.var);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cannot do it with "int" -- there is only "pass-by-value" in Java. Still, can simulate easily w/ AtomicInteger:

```
static void test(AtomicInteger i)
{
    i.addAndGet(2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(3);
    test(i);
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-static member function can only be invoked on an object instance. It can't be called "on its own".

You have two options:

1. make `Receiving` static;
2. create an instance of `Test` in main and call `test.Receiving(3)`.

Either way, `var` will be passed into the function by value, so `main` will not see the changed value. To get around that, you have several options, which include:

1. making `var` into a single-element array,
2. using [`AtomicInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) (it isn't really designed for this, but I often see it used in this manner).

Answer (score 0):

It often much clearer in Java for the caller to use a function as you should expect methods to change the object but not its arguments.

```
public static int receiving (int var) {
    return var + 2;
}

public static void main(String... args){
    int passing = 3;
    // its clear passing can be changed.
    passing = receiving(passing); 
    System.out.println("The value of passing is: " +passing);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The primitive type are passed by value. Java Objects are always referenced and its reference is always passed by value.

As for the static error, there's two ways to resolve it:

1. Make `receiving` `static`, or:
2. create a `Test` object and call `receiving`.

Example:

```
Test test = new Test();
test.Receiving(passing);
```

To pass by reference, you will have to pass a reference of the object to the method (of which java will pass the reference by value) and do the calculation from there. An array of int or `AtomicInteger` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Passing by reference isn't possible in Java, and Objects aren't passed at all: [Article on passing](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html)

You could however

1. Use a return value in your function and use that value in your main program
2. Declare a static value at the top. Then your value would have a scope of the whole program though, not sure you want that

Comment: To be picky, it's not possible with references either.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, thanks! I'll edit the post to be more acurate. :)

Answer (score 0):

What others have said above is quite true.
But if you just want to get 5 as your final output there are numerous ways to achieve that. I have posted below one of them.

```
public class NewClass {

     static int passing = 3;

    public static void Receiving (int var)
    {
      var = var + 2;
      passing = var;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

      Receiving (passing);

      System.out.println("The value of passing is: " +passing);
    }
```

}

I know this is not a good approach but i felt you were hell bent on getting 5 printed....